# How can I measure the control loop time?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new in ROS and I will like to know how to measure the control loop time? how do I know at what frecuency is the control loop running?
how can I test it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262675/how-can-i-measure-the-control-loop-time?/) by [Jorge Jiménez](https://answers.ros.org/users/30534/jorge-jim%C3%A9nez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does it publish any topics? The easiest way I can think of is:

```
rostopic hz topic_name
```

[rostopic wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_hz)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1